# trying to read a file

Tags: c, antivirus, antivirus-integration

basically trying to make an anti virus but all I get when trying to read the infected file into a buffer is EOF... it's a jpg and I have no idea how to fix this

about the file functions I'm allowed to use:
fread/fwrite
fgets
fputs
fclose
fopen
fgetc
fputc
fscanf
fprintf

```
int fullScan(FILE* sign, FILE* infected);
char* getFile(FILE* file);

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    FILE* sign = fopen("KittenVirusSign", "rb");
    FILE* infected = fopen("kitten_frog.jpg", "rb");
    int j = 0;
    if (infected == NULL)
    {
        printf("couldn't open the file (suspicious file)");
        return -1;
    }
    if (sign == NULL)
    {
        printf("couldn't open the file (virus signature)");
        return -1;
    }

    j = fullScan(sign, infected);
    return 0;
}

int fullScan(FILE* sign, FILE* infected)
{
    char* sign_c = NULL;
    char* infec_c = NULL;
    int infect_res = -1;
    int sign_len = 0;
    int infec_len = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    sign_c = getFile(sign);
    infec_c = getFile(infected);
    while (1)
    {

        if (*(infec_c + i) == *(sign_c + j))
        {
            infect_res = 1;
            if (*(sign_c + j) == EOF)
            {
                break;
            }
            else if (*(infec_c + i) == EOF)
            {
                infect_res = -1;
                break;
            }
            i++;
            j++;
            continue;
        }
        else if (*(infec_c + i) != *(sign_c + j))
        {
            if (*(infec_c + i) == EOF || *(sign_c + j) == EOF)
            {
                break;
            }
            i++;
            j = 0;
            infect_res = -1;
        }

    }
    fclose(infected);
    free(sign_c);
    free(infec_c);
    return infect_res;
}


char* getFile(FILE* file)
{
    char* buffer;
    long filelen;
    int i;
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
    filelen = ftell(file);
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);
    buffer = (char *)malloc((filelen + 1)*sizeof(char));
    for (i = 0; i < filelen; i++)
    {
        fread(buffer + i, sizeof(char), 1, file);
    }

    return buffer;
}
```

Comment: sign_c comes perfectly fine but infec_c is having problems

Comment: what actually happens when you run the program? what kind of output are you expecting, and what do you get instead?

Comment: - Erik Nyquist I'm expecting to get the binary values of a jpg image (using getFile) and then check to see if the sign (virus signature) exists in the file, the virus signature goes perfectly fine but the image doesn't.

Comment: when calling any of the memory allocation family of functions: (malloc, calloc, realloc) 1) do not cast the returned value.  2) the expression: `sizeof(char)` is defined in the C standard as 1 and multiplying by 1 has absolutely no effect on the parameter passed. 3) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful

Comment: when calling the system functions: `fseek()`, `fread()`, always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: when the parameters to main() are not used, then use the signature: `int main( void )`

Comment: the variable `j` is set in two places in the posted code, but that value is never used.

Answer (score 1):

`EOF` is a special integer value returned by some input functions to indicate that the end of the file has been reached, but it is not part of the file data.  Your `fread()` will therefore never store an EOF character into the input buffer you provided.  However, if your C implementation features signed default `char`s, as many do, then there is a `char` value that is numerically equal to `EOF` (usually -1).

If either file happens to contain that byte, then your code will misinterpret it as designating the end of that file.  If it happens to be the first byte in either file then the program will misinterpret the file as being empty.

Since you are analyzing binary files,

1. I recommend using buffers of `unsigned char` rather than default `char`.
2. All possible byte values can appear in the file data, so you cannot identify the end of the data by the value of any byte within.

Probably, `getFile()` should return a struct that contains both a pointer to the buffer and its size.

Comment: so using an unsigned char won't result in me losing bytes of the file when storing it? thanks for the help, would really appreciate if you could answer that last question -John Bollinger --- edit: still doesn't work, getting errors now (runtime)

Comment: @teggr234, using `unsigned char` instead of `char` emphasizes that you're examining binary data rather than character data, and it changes the *interpretation* of the bits read from the file, but no bits are lost that way.  Anyway, the recommendation to use `unsigned char` is just that -- a recommendation.  Solving the problem does not depend on it.

Comment: yeah, still wouldn't work.. I'm still getting EOF for some reason and I have no idea why..

Comment: @teggr234, read the answer again.  The change to `unsigned char` is only a recommendation, but the answer also explains why what you are doing overall is incorrect, and suggests a viable solution.  Just to reiterate, however: you cannot detect the end of the file data based on the values of the bytes in the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

As other answer suggested, you should also send the file length and iterate over that, rather than waiting for a `EOF`.

Also, in your `getFile()` function, when you determine the length of the file you don't have to read byte by byte, you can just send the `filelen` to `fread()` like so

```
fread(buffer, sizeof(char), filelen, file);
```

`fread` now reads `filelen` elements of data each the size of a char (you can write 1 instead) from the stream `file` to `buffer`.